# How can I let anonymous users comment only once?

Tags: 7, comments

I'd like anonymous users to be able to comment only once on a node. I thought about checking whether there's already a comment from the user's IP-adress and, if yes, hiding the comment form, but I don't know how to do that.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by means of two functions called [flood_register_event()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/flood_register_event/7) and 
 [flood_is_allowed()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/flood_is_allowed/7).

When a anon user views a node, call `flood_is_allowed` in `hook_node_view` that sets `COMMENT_NODE_CLOSED` for the node.

When a anon user comments, register that as a flood event in `hook_comment_presave` for that particular node. By setting the `$threshold` (parameter for `flood_is_allowed`) to 1, the user will be stopped from commenting after the first comment is posted.

This is the bare bones of how to implement hooks that make use of these functions:

```
function MYMODULE_comment_presave($comment) {
  global $user;
  if (!$user->uid) {
    flood_register_event($comment->nid);
  }
}
function MYMODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  global $user;
  if (!$user->uid && !flood_is_allowed($node->nid, 1)) {
    // This bars the anon user from posting a second comment of the node.
    // For a more sophisticated blocking method (e.g. to prevent the comment form from
    // showing up), ask another question about how to do that.
    $node->comment = COMMENT_NODE_CLOSED;
  }
}
```

PS: The module [Anonymous Publishing](https://drupal.org/project/anonymous_publishing) is already using this pair of functions to limit the number of comments an anonymous user can post (but not exactly in the way you specify).  However, looking at the source code of that module should give you an idea about how to use this pair of functions for flood control of anonymous comments.

Comment: Thanks for the code! I've added it to my custom module, but it doesn't seem to work. Is that normal? It looks fine to me. Did you test it?

Comment: Yes, I've tested  it. As I said; It is bare bones, to show how to use these two functions to prevent the anon user from posting more than one comment for a single node within one hour. There is plenty of work (such as actually *removing* the comment form from display, or extending the period the flood control is enforced) left for *you* to do.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I've been able to let it work. Your code wasn't very far from the solution. I found the last necessary hint at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4513/enable-disable-comment-form-in-a-module.